# How to disable field conditionally in Svelte?

Tags: html, svelte

In Angular 2+ (for example), I can use this syntax to disable a field conditionally:

```
<input [disabled]="booleanCondition" type="text">
```

In Svelte I'm trying to do as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
<input {booleanCondition ? 'disabled=""' : ''} type="text">
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Like this](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.6.1&gist=7d2a2b6cc521a399d46fb913ea774178):

```html
<input disabled={booleanCondition}>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
  let disabled = true;
</script>

<input {disabled} type="text"/>
```

This is the shorthand for:

```
<script>
  let disabled = true;
</script>

<input disabled={disabled} type="text"/>
```

It works because when the attribute name and value match (name={name}), they can be replaced with {name}.

You can find this at [Svelte Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-tags)

Works the same in a button:

```
<button {disabled}>Can't Click</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I'd add to the accepted answer, that one can pass an external (with respect to the component) boolean value as follows:

```html
<!-- Nested.svelte -->
<input disabled={ $$props.disabled }>
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<Nested disabled={ booleanCondition }/>
```

To generalize the approach:

```html
<!-- Nested.svelte -->
<script>
const { type, name, required, disabled } = $$props
</script>
<input { type } { name } { required } { disabled }>
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<Nested type="text" name="myName" required disabled={ booleanCondition }/>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it fully working in SSR and CSR, use the below code:

```
<input disabled={booleanCondition || null} type="text">
```